# How do you dim a LED streetlight 12V DC? Can it be done thru controlling the current?

Tags: led

How do you dim a LED streetlight 12V DC? Can it be done thru controlling the current?

Thanks for answering. This is for our thesis.

Comment: Usually, the best way is using PWM.

Comment: Use PWM to control your LED. Can refer this http://www.ijsr.net/archive/v3i11/T0NUMTQxMTYx.pdf

Comment: Another useful reference: http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/lighting/led-dimmer-circuit/

Comment: a series resistor is more efficient than PWM

Comment: Thesis project? Shouldn't you be answering all the questions? Do you have an advisor?

Comment: @Jasen How is a series resistor more efficient than PWM? *Simpler* yes, efficient? Perhaps not - especially for larger LED arrays. Besides, dropping the current can result in changes in the LED's colour spectrum (well, for 'white' LEDs anyway) whereas PWM maintains a consistent colour.

Comment: With a resistor you don't need to drive the switch.  LEDs respond to current, unlike incandescent lamps which respond to power.  With PWM you're just putting more heat into the LED (instead of into the resistor). Better results than both PWM and resistors are had using switched-mode power-supplies.

Answer (score 1):

Usually light dimming is accomplished by using Pulse Width Modulation (PWM). Pulses of some duty cycle determine the brightness, for example, 50 % duty cycle would approximately halve your input voltage peak value. The trick is that you don't change amplitude but rather change average value. Applying some low pass filtering might smooth output voltage for applications that don't like sharp transitions much such as some lasers. Wouldn't advice it for high power applications.

Yes, you can do it while controlling current and it's probably a better way. You would need voltage controlled current source such as LT8613 - modulating some adjustment pin with some voltage (using ADC or something similar) you would change voltage across current setting resistor which determines the limit current which flows through your lamp. When selecting such source make sure you select correct topology because otherwise it won't work.

Comment: pwm works great for incandescent lamps, but for LEDs it's inefficient,  use a switching regulator instead.